# why does my react-native app crash when I open a certain screen?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am building an app to show information of how covid is affected by different factors, like climate, and co2 level. So I used a webview to bring in a map from NASA. But when I navigate to that specific screen. The app crashes. It works fine sometimes, and crash mostly. My code is

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const GreenHouseScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
     <WebView
            style={{width: 600, height: 500}}
    source={{uri: 'https://eodashboard.org/iframe?poi=W4-N2'}}
/> 
    </View>
  )
}

export default GreenHouseScreen```
````

Comment: You must import React even if you are not using React.

Comment: Importing that didnt make a difference